# Why the string is always empty?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I try to use LINQ to read XML file. However, the string which store the value of selected attribute is always empty.

Here is the code:

```
        string output = "";
        XDocument loaded = XDocument.Load(@"d:\input.xml");

        var ta = from tmp in loaded.Descendants("NewDataSet.Table")
                select tmp.Element("E1");

        foreach (string ss in ta)
        {
            ouput += ss;

        }
```

The `output` string is always empty. But the `ss` string has correct value.

What is the problem?

I've no idea how to add xml file with style. So i have to update the xml file as image. :(
[image]

Comment: Please post a (small) representative XML document.

Comment: If you debug your code step-by-step, what do you see in `output` when the current sentence (the debugger's yellow-bg line) reaches the closing curly bracket `}` ?

Comment: sorry guys but everyone trying to help here is downvoted today - nice behaviour by all those sherrifs here - I guess I will call it a day and not help anyone around here for now - maybe all those nice little downvoters go away finally - but honestly: this side was made to help not to charg up your ego ... yes this is a completly OT rant but had to say it

Comment: @CKoenig, it's nice that you are trying to help. We all are. The thing is that when a question is not clear you use the comments section to ask for clarification from the OP, exactly as Oded did. Remember that StackOverflow is a site which should serve as a reference also for other people that might have the same problem, not only help the OP. Posting answers that only ask for more details, as you did, are meaningless in the future. This being said, I didn't downvote your answer. I just posted a comment on it, but other people downvoted it and I am not against.

Comment: yes and if you answer the question by stating that based on the info you've seen it has to be the format of the xml (which was right as you can see now) and getting a downvote for is really nice ... as you got your score for this I think we can settle this ... nice rep technique (works well with high rep huh?)

Comment: Sheesh - I didn't see the answer you gave @CKoenig, but your repsonse to Darin strikes me as uncalled for, especially since he said he didn't downvote you.  He has a high rep score because he's answered more questions and gotten more accepts than you (or me, for that matter).  In this case, his answer (of the three I see) was the most complete.

Comment: To get XML nicely formatted, just paste it in and indent 4 spaces, like any other piece of code (highlight it and click the `{}` button).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now that you have shown your XML, here's how to fix your code:

```
var ta = from tmp in loaded.Descendants("Table")
         select tmp.Element("E1");
```

You do not use `.` in XML as you do in C# to navigate the XML tree. You could also navigate a XML tree using [XPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342176.aspx):

```
var ta = from tmp in loaded.XPathSelectElements("NewDataSet/Table/E1")
         select tmp;
```

Also I would recommend you to use a StringBuilder instead of string concatenations for this output variable:

```
var ta = from tmp in loaded.Descendants("Table")
         select tmp.Element("E1");

var builder = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string ss in ta)
{
    builder.Append(ss);
}
string output = builder.ToString();
```

Comment: Profile before recommending optimisations, and prefer StringWriter to StringBuilder.

Comment: @Binary Worrier +1, and for the given XML sample prefer 'string' to either.

Answer (score 0):

```
var ta = from tmp in loaded.Descendants("Table")
select tmp.Element("E1");
```